# Hosts file and viewing sites which are https

Tags: windows, https, iis-6

I have a windows server behind a NAT, so in order to view any of the sites the server is running I have a hosts file setup to point to point back to the right internal IP.

e.g.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.0.1     www.mydomain.com
```

This is all fine and I can view the site www.mydomain.com on the local machine.

This issue I am having is that I cant view the https of the site on the local machine 
e.g. https://www.mydomain.com returns an error, that it cant connect.

From any webbroswer outside the server enviroment it all works fine its just when I go to view the site view on the local machine.

What should I be adding to the hosts file / doing to make the site connect locally over SSL?

Comment: Right figured out the answer, I needed to flush the local DNS cache after changing the hosts file over to the new IP in order for it to work properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nothing more should be added to hosts file. Just configure your IIS server to server https as well.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069

Comment: IIS is setup for https and the live site is working fine via https, this is only an issue when looking at the site on the server.